# Can log4j's error method print stack trace without string argument?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

In regards to Log4j v2, I'd like to call log.error(exceptionTypeObj) and have the stack trace printed to my logfile instead of exceptionTypeObj.toString(). Is that possible?

I'd rather write code like `log.error(e)` and be done with it.

It's error prone and redundant for me to keep writing something like log.error("error", exceptionTypeObj).

Comment: It’s redundant because you have no regard for the person reading the log.  Why not actually specify a message describing what failed?  For instance, `log.error("Unable to read file \"" + file + "\"", e);`

Answer (score 2):

The String parameter is redundant because you are not using it for the correct purpose. An Exception will tell you what error occurred but it won't tell you what you were trying to do when it happened. That is why you should always provide the string. Provide a String that says something like "Error occurred while attempting to update the user profile for user {}", and then provide the user name or id.

Without the String parameter you are forcing your support staff to call engineering to find out what the exception means and what they should do about it.